# Django Pgencrypt - AttributeError: 'Col' object has no attribute 'source'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use this library with Django:

https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto/

I've tried setting up my field like this:

```
username = pgcrypto.EncryptedTextField(cipher='AES', key='datekey')
```

This:

```
username = pgcrypto.EncryptedTextField(cipher='AES')
```

And this:

```
username = pgcrypto.EncryptedTextField()
```

In each case, I am receiving the same error when I make a query:

File "/blahblahblah/python2.7/site-packages/pgcrypto/fields.py", line 221, in as_postgresql
    params = lhs_params + [self.lhs.source.cipher_key] + rhs_params
AttributeError: 'Col' object has no attribute 'source'

Now I'm looking at the class this happens in:

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 7):

    from django.db.models.lookups import Lookup

    class EncryptedLookup (Lookup):
        def as_postgresql(self, qn, connection):
            lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(qn, connection)
            rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(qn, connection)
            params = lhs_params + [self.lhs.source.cipher_key] + rhs_params
            rhs = connection.operators[self.lookup_name] % rhs
            cipher = {
                'AES': 'aes',
                'Blowfish': 'bf',
            }[self.lhs.source.cipher_name]
            return "convert_from(decrypt(dearmor(%s), %%s, '%s'), 'utf-8')%s %s" % \
                (lhs, cipher, self.lhs.source.field_cast, rhs), params

    for lookup_name in ('exact', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'):
        class_name = 'EncryptedLookup_%s' % lookup_name
        lookup_class = type(class_name, (EncryptedLookup,), {'lookup_name': lookup_name})
        BaseEncryptedField.register_lookup(lookup_class)
```

And it seems to be looking for a source and a cipher_key on the lhs variable (which I'm guessing stands for left-hand side).

How do I add a source for this lhs variable?

Is there any configuration setting that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same message and filed a bugreport for it here:
https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto/issues/17